# My forms widget is not scrolling. How to define the size of the forms widget in flutter, complete form is not shown or visible

Tags: forms, flutter

My forms widget is not scrolling. How to define the size of the forms widget in flutter, complete form is not shown or visible. The user has to enter the following data / information and submit

folowing is  my code  `

```
class  MiMobilesPageState extends State<MiMobilesPage> {
  String _companyname;
  String _modelname;
  String _series;
  String _year;
  String _serielnumber;
  String _warrantydate;
  String _servicecentredetails;
  String _name;
  String _mobilenumber;
  String _address;

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _buildCompanyName() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'CompanyName'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Company Name is Required';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _companyname = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildModelName() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'ModelName'),
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Model Name';
        }


      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _modelname = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSeries() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Series'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Series is Required';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _series = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildYear() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Year'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Year of MFG is Required';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _year = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSerielNumber() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'SerielNumber'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      maxLength: 20,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Seriel-Number is Required';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _serielnumber = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWarrantyDate() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Warranty-Date'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String value) {
        int date = int.tryParse(value);

        if (date == null || date <= 0) {
          return 'Warranty Date must be greater than 0';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _warrantydate = value;
      },
    );
  }


  Widget _buildServiceCentreDetails() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'ServiceCentreDetails'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Service Centre Details are  Required';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _servicecentredetails = value;
      },
    );
  }



  Widget _buildName() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Name is Required';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _name = value;
      },
    );
  }



  Widget _buildMobileNumber() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'MobileNumber'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Mobile Number is Required';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _mobilenumber = value;
      },
    );
  }



  Widget _buildAddress() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Address is Required';
        }
        if (!RegExp(
            r"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
            .hasMatch(value)) {
          return 'Please enter a valid Address';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _companyname = value;
      },
    );
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true,backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,title: Text("Basic Details",style:
      TextStyle(fontSize: 20), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          actions:<Widget>[IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.home),  onPressed: (){
      //debugPrint("Add New Device Cattegorry");
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context){
        return MyHomePage();
      }
      )
      ); //
    },



    )    ],






      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget> [
              _buildCompanyName(),
              _buildModelName(),
              _buildSeries(),
              _buildYear(),
              _buildSerielNumber(),
              _buildWarrantyDate(),
              _buildServiceCentreDetails(),
              _buildName(),
              _buildMobileNumber(),
              _buildAddress(),

              SizedBox(height:400),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Submit',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    return;
                  }

                  _formKey.currentState.save();

                  print(_companyname);
                  print(_modelname);
                  print(_series);
                  print(_year);
                  print(_serielnumber);
                  print(_warrantydate);
                  print(_servicecentredetails);
                  print(_name);
                  print(_mobilenumber);
                  print(_address);

                  //Send to API
                },


              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please guide where I am wrong what is to be included in the code and what changes have to be made?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `SizedBox(height:400),` was a typo, meant to be `40`?

To make your `Form` scroll, you'll need to wrap it in a `Scrollable` widget usually a `ListView` or a `SingleChildScrollView`.

I added an example using your code:

```dart
 body: SingleChildScrollView( // wrap with SingleChildScrollView to allow scrolls
          child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Form(
          // key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildCompanyName(),
              _buildModelName(),
              _buildSeries(),
              _buildYear(),
              _buildSerielNumber(),
              _buildWarrantyDate(),
              _buildServiceCentreDetails(),
              _buildName(),
              _buildMobileNumber(),
              _buildAddress(),

              SizedBox(height:400), // incase this is not an error as I assumed, change to 400
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Submit',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    return;
                  }

                  _formKey.currentState.save();

                  print(_companyname);
                  print(_modelname);
                  print(_series);
                  print(_year);
                  print(_serielnumber);
                  print(_warrantydate);
                  print(_servicecentredetails);
                  print(_name);
                  print(_mobilenumber);
                  print(_address);

                  //Send to API
                },

              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you now  my form widget is scrolling perfectly. It is working even for  SizedBox(height:100),. I think it is not the issue. But I dont know where the form data is submitting. The submission is not happening. I mean  where will it get saved or stored after submission.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView` if you want it to scroll.

Like this

```
Form(
 child: SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
     children: [...]
    )
 )
)
```